# How to decrypt RSA encrypted file (via PHP and OpenSSL) with pyopenssl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, pyopenssl

Simple n00b question: I am trying to replicate the behavior of the [openssl_private_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php) function in PHP to decrypt a file that a vendor is sending me which was encrypted via the [openssl_public_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) function. I am using python 3.4 and thus the only library I can see available is [pyopenssl](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl), but it's sufficiently low-level that I cannot easily find out how to do what I want to do. It's probably very simple, but does anyone have an exemple of what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mnistic it got to work, with a couple of modifications though. Here is the final working code (you have to keep in mind the defaults of [openssl_private_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php)):

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

# It's critical that the file be opened in mode "rb"!
with open("private.key", 'rb') as key_file:
  private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(key_file.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())

with open('encrypted_file', 'rb') as encrypted_file:
  ciphertext = encrypted_file.read()

plaintext = private_key.decrypt(ciphertext, padding.PKCS1v15())
```

Please note that `ciphertext` needs to be shorter than the maximum chunk size of the key (which is the number of bits in the key divided by 8 for RSA). Hope that helps future Googlers!

Answer (score 1):

With the [Cryptography module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/), which you can install with:

`$ pip install cryptography`

Assuming you have the private key stored in a file called "path/to/key.pem", first you load the private key:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization 
with open("path/to/key.pem", "rb") as key_file: 
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend() 
    )
```

And then you decrypt with:

```
plaintext = private_key.decrypt(
    ciphertext,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
            label=None
    )
)
```